# How to open modal in vue router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Is somebody knows how can I display my modal window with this code `this.$modal.showForm('Login)'` in vue-router? When I do it in Vue componetnt it's OK but when I try to open it in vue-router I've got an error **Cannot read property '$modal' of undefined**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modal must exists in a component. To show it on route changed, you can use the `mounted`  hook of the component.

```
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'the-component',
    mounted () {
      this.$modal.showForm('Login)'
    }
  }
</script>
```

By the way, you can listen to route changed in the layout and fire the dialog when needed:

```
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'the-layout',

    beforeRouteUpdate () {
      if(this.$route.name === 'xyz'){
        this.$modal.showForm('Login)'
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```